# Oracle External Table - How to convert field to a date?

Tags: oracle

I'm loading some data into oracle using an external table. One of the fields "CREATEDON" is a date but is formatted like this 20151231

How can I convert CREATEDON to a proper oracle date datatype. This is my attempt so far which doesn't work...

```
  CREATE TABLE "AMS"."DATA" 
   (    "BLANK" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "BLANK2" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "CLIENT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "MATERIAL" DATE, 
    "CREATEDON" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DIR"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( records delimited BY '\r\n' 
                skip 1 
      fields terminated BY '|' lrtrim missing field VALUES are NULL 
            )
      LOCATION  ( "DIR":'foo.txt'      )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Keep as is, and transform in your select statements, such as:

   select ..., to_date(CREATEDON,'YYYYMMDD') CREATEDON
2. Define the format in the table DDL:

"CREATEDON" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DATE_FORMAT DATE MASK "YYYYMMDD"

Comment: You can't define the table DLL for external tables can you?

Comment: Well, yes, the CREATE statement you have above is "DDL" , just with the addition of the external table bits.

Comment: Sorry but it won't let me create the statement as you suggested, I get errors about parenthesis missing.  Could you post an example of what my create table statement should look like please